# Getting a View of current visible activity launched by other SDK

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk

I am using a SDK (library like we use for payments or ads or some app which opens a webview), which is launching an activity. How Can I get the view instance of this activity which is launched by the SDK.

One method I know is to use ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks. But is there any other simple way to get this??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by SDK? A library? Another app launched using an Intent?

Comment: library like we use for payments or ads or some app which opens a webview

Answer (score -1):

**You can not**. Android is a secure system and prohibits access to things you should not access.

In case of another app, it will be started as a separate process with no direct access and no access at all to things like views or Java objects. You should follow the documentation of the app developer, pass all data you need to pass in an `Intent` and await a response if needed.

In case of a library, you will not have access to `Activities` opened by it, as they are treated as closed components. It is possible that the developer created some sort of interface which would allow that, but there is no standard way to do this.

There is one workaround:
If the library is open source, you may choose to clone its repository and add the code locally to your app. This way you will be able to edit it and receive access to the components. **But this will probably not work with secure things like payments or ads.**

Again, just follow the documentation provided by the developer, be a good citizen :-)